# What's the logic of the versioning in symfony fos rest bundle?

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

It seems there's no clear explanation on the versioning of the fos rest bundle:

1) The default version value is null. What about 2 or "2" or "v2"?

    `versioning:
        enabled: true
        default_version: null`

2) If I mark the default_version to version 2, and define a controller as `@Version("v2")` (or "2" ?), but the version in the request is "v1", will it throw error or just go using v2?

3) What about default version is 1, request is 1, but the controller is 2?

...

The document is not very clear as when I read it.